# Interactive plotly 2D graphic disappears when a 3D graphic is added

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, interactive

I have a plot made in plotly in which I use a button to switch from 2D to 3D visualisation. When I add add_trace to the 3D graph I lose the interactivity of the 2D plotly graph. I've tested with or without the button and it doesn't work either. It's really the addition of the 3D graph that disturbs the 2D graph.

```
library(plotly)

n <- 100
group <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, replace = TRUE)
x <- rnorm(n, mean = ifelse(group == "A", 0, ifelse(group == "B", 3, 6)))
y <- rnorm(n, mean = ifelse(group == "A", 0, ifelse(group == "B", 3, 6)))
z <- rnorm(n, mean = ifelse(group == "A", 0, ifelse(group == "B", 3, 6)))


df3d <- data.frame(x = x,
                   y = y,
                   z = z,
                   group = group)

colors <- c("blue", "green", "red")

buttons <- list(
  list(
    method = 'restyle',
    args = list('visible', list(TRUE, FALSE)),
    label = '2D'
  ),
  list(
    method = 'restyle',
    args = list('visible', list(FALSE, TRUE)),
    label = '3D'
  )
)

fig <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    data = df3d,
    x = ~ x,
    y = ~ y,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers',
    name = '2D',
    marker = list(
      size = 10,
      color = colors[match(group, unique(group))],
      opacity = 0.7
    ),
    visible = TRUE
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    data = df3d,
    x = ~ x,
    y = ~ y,
    z = ~ z,
    type = 'scatter3d',
    mode = 'markers',
    name = '3D',
    marker = list(
      size = 10,
      color = colors[match(group, unique(group))],
      opacity = 0.7
    ),
    visible = FALSE
  ) %>%
  layout(title = 'Nuage de points',
         showlegend = FALSE,
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             buttons = buttons,
             direction = 'down',
             pad = list('r', 10),
             showactive = TRUE,
             x = 0.1,
             xanchor = 'left',
             y = 1.1,
             yanchor = 'top'
           )
         ))

fig
```